# Placing tiles on concrete wall

Tags: bathroom

The bathroom tiles in my shower began to let loose, we decided to rip them off (I'll admit it wasn't a good idea), but with the tiles, the cement also came off. I would just cover it in cement again and place some new tiles but the cement at the top and bottom also came lose so the tiles are now 'movable'.

I've included a video of the problem so you can click [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XuinovHFEts&feature=youtu.be) to view it. I was wonder what's the best way to go about fixing this? I thought about just cementing over the concrete and placing new tiles but I'm afraid the top ones will let lose too, but the other hand if I take those off to I think I'll just end up taking the whole wall out :(

[image: My very beautiful wall]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is almost no chance that is concrete.   That looks like some kind of concrete board material (if that) with mastic slapped on and tiles.

Everything has to come down.

If it is concrete (don't think it is) then you need to assess the shower.   If the concrete is in good shape, remove any damaged concrete the put a skim coat of thinset, let dry.   Then tile with a generous amount of thinset (different question).

If it is not concrete - after you assess when tile is removed... ask a new question and more than happy to help.   A concrete shower is awesome... unless you want it to be a different size!

Comment: I see thank you very much for the advice! I think I'll just have a professional do it then, since I'm a bit out of my league if I'll have to retile the entire bathroom :/

Answer (score 1):

I cannot tell what was used to attach your tile but can say it was not the correct material. If a mastic most mastics are water based and a bad choice for both concrete wall and shower stall, I also see no evidence of the set there should be ridges or notches that are flattened out , also a good tile job is “back buttered” with a concrete wall if done properly the tiles should be just about impossible to remove even under water.

Comment: I don't think it is concrete.

Comment: Ahh, thank you! The bathroom was constructed after the house was delivered and the guy who did it also hooked up the electric wiring weird so I think he's just very inexperienced or didn't care.. :/

Comment: A modular would be 100% some kind of backer board so now we are down to the tiles not being properly attached, some electricians have multiple skills,  prior to my apprenticeship I did thousands of square feet of tile work and I still do small jobs for friends and family. But this was not done correctly as I stated. Knowing it is backer that white is probably a mastic I would scrape it as it doesn’t look like it was worked into the backer so that may be salvageable DIY, but a pro will probably want to do a rip and strip then start new time is $.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the waterproofing has failed, all those tiles will have to come out. then the waterproofing be re-done, then re-tiled.

Comment: Waterproofing on a concrete wall?